# Java performance ByteBuffer copying from heap to direct or direct to direct

Tags: java, performance, bytebuffer

My question is which is faster:

Copying a heap ByteBuffer to a direct ByteBuffer 
OR
coping a direct ByteBuffer to a direct ByteBuffer.

From what I can tell the direct to direct approach will use the Unsafe.copyMemory otherwise if a heap array exists it will use the Bits.copyFromByteArray method, following that a while loop extracting each byte from the heap ByteBuffer to the direct ByteBuffer will be used.

I assuming that the Unsafe.copyMemory will be faster, since this seems to be done outside the JVM, but I am not sure.

Has any one benchmarked the three different approaches?

Thanks!

Comment: http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/readingwriting-gc-less-memory.html

Comment: What happened when *you* measured it?